# How to start/stop services using Perl CGI script

Tags: linux, apache, perl, cgi

My aim is to start/stop services(like httpd, sshd, iptables, etc) from a Perl CGI Script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "content-type:text/html\n\n";
print <<EOM;
<html>
<body>
EOM
`/etc/init.d/httpd stop`;
my $res=`/etc/init.d/httpd status`;
print <<EOM;
<h3>$res</h3>
</body>
</html>
EOM
```

Here the first command inside back tics isn't working, whereas the second command which is assigned to $res is working. 
Output on the browser is as follows:

```
httpd (pid 15657) is running...
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the output of running the stop command?

Comment: It's printing like this:                                        Stopping httpd: [FAILED]

Comment: Perhaps the user running the CGI script has not the right to start/stop the service.

Comment: Do I get that right: You are trying to stop the HTTP server while it is serving your script? Like unmounting a car's wheel while driving?

Comment: I wonder how he tries to start it again ... ;)

Comment: If the httpd service is stopped, then i'm going to get an error in my browser which will indicate that the service is stopped..But the problem is its httpd or any other service-it's not working.And if the user while running the script is apache than how is it displaying the status.I mean that user may not have the permission to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest displaying the output from the `stop` command. I strongly suspect that you will see an error indicating that you do not have permission to stop the service.

A correctly configured web server process will be owned by a user that has almost no permissions on the system. This is a security feature. CGI programs on your web server can be run by anyone who can access the web server. For that reason, the web server user is usually configured to only run a very limited set of programs.

Starting and stopping your web server is something that you will usually need root permissions for. Your web server process will not have root permissions (for, hopefully, obvious reasons). But it's entirely possible that every user on the system (including the web server user) will have permissions to get the status of the web server process. This is why your `httpd status` command works, while the `httpd stop` command doesn't.

You could give the web server user temporary permission to start or stop services, using `sudo` or something like that. But you would need to do it very carefully - perhaps requiring a password on the web page (and transmitting that password securely over https).

But it's probably a better idea to reconsider this approach completely.

Can I also point that it's a bad idea to use backticks to run external commands that you don't want to collect the output from. In cases like that, it will be more efficient to use the `system()` function.

I also note, that you are loading the CGI module, but not using any of its functionality. You even manually create your `Content-Type` header, ignoring the module's `header()` function.

And here's my traditional admonition that writing new CGI programs in 2017 is a terrible idea. Please read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and consider a PSGI-based approach instead.

Comment: Points noted.Thanks for your advice.Actually I'm new to the CGI environment.The other way i want to try is to login as root user and execute that command.Is it possible to login to root from the script or the other option is to give sudo rights to the apache user.which one will be better and ease my task?

Comment: *Actually I'm new to the CGI environment.* @VamseeBond: Then please stop. Learning CGI in 2017 is ridiculous.

Comment: @VamseeBond I am not a stringently against learning CGI, but you need to find a different task to learn. One that does not involve gaping backdoors to the system.

Comment: @VamseeBond: That's great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not even think of having a CGI script which has the privileges to start/stop services on a computer. There are, of course, valid reasons to want to have remote control over servers, but if giving the HTTP daemon super user privileges is the only way you can think of achieving that end, you need to realize that you ought not to be the person implementing that functionality.